# Change value of a var?

Tags: jquery, jplayer

@Walter Ok I did take your advice and I started the codecademy lessons, complted 50 tasks so far. Now it is nice to learn and I will continue the whole course. But understand I am not an IT guy or student, I am 46 years old and only running a simple radio website. Now you say "stackoverflow" is not for beginners, but then try to google for anwers, 90% of all hits go to stackoverflow. As said, I will continue my course on codecademy but for now can somebody PLEASE help me with the below problem?

I want to make a button on my radio page so that people can switch between different channels but I have no clue where to start. I was thinking to make a button with an onclick function in jquery and mak it change the value of "mp3" but how ?

I tried this at the bottom of the script but that does nothing;

```
$("#button_pop").click(function(){
    stream.mp3 = "http://212.83.178.251:8000/stream";
});
```

This is the current code;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var stream = {

    title: "FSN Radio",
    mp3: "http://212.83.178.251:8050/stream"
},

ready = false;

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({

    ready: function (event) {

        ready = true;

        $(this).jPlayer("play", stream);

    },

    pause: function() {

        $(this).jPlayer("clearMedia");

    },

    error: function(event) {

        if(ready && event.jPlayer.error.type === $.jPlayer.error.URL_NOT_SET) {

            // Setup the media stream again and play it.

            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream).jPlayer("play");
        }
    },
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "mp3",
    preload: "none",
    wmode: "window",
    volume: 0.02,
    solution: 'html,flash',
    keyEnabled: true
});
```

});

Comment: Is this your first time programming in JavaScript? `stream.mp3 = 'new value';`

Comment: Yes, started to learn 3 weeks ago and all is self study so it goes slow. Untill now I was able to just use examples and edit them, but this one I didnt know and didnt know how to search for it.

Comment: stream isn't in your function scope

Comment: @Revdutchie StackOverflow isn't really intended for beginner programmers. I'm not saying you're not welcome, but you may have trouble getting answers for highly trivial questions such as this one. I suggest learning via http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript and as Alvarez said, google "javascript scope" or "programming scope" in general

Comment: Walter, ok point taken. I am trying to learn from w3schools but as I said it goes slow also because english aint my native language it is sometimes hard to understand the explanation.

Comment: @Walter Ok I did take your advice and I started the codecademy lessons, complted 50 tasks so far. Now it is nice to learn and I will continue the whole course. But understand I am not an IT guy or student, I am 46 years old and only running a simple radio website. Now you say "stackoverflow" is not for beginners, but then try to google for anwers, 90% of all hits go to stackoverflow. As said, I will continue my course on codecademy but for now can somebody PLEASE help me with above problem?

Comment: You bring up a very interesting point about Google results being flooded with links to SO. Here is a good thread to read about being a [new programmer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/740639) on SO. Also, if you think programming really isn't for you, but you want to spruce up your website, consider hiring some neighborhood kid that knows about programming.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). To fix it,  move

```
var stream = {

    title: "FSN Radio",
    mp3: "http://212.83.178.251:8050/stream"
},

ready = false;
```

outside of your `$(document).ready(function(){` block.

Comment: Ok, done that and due to the link you gave me on codecademy I even understand why this was needed (I think) If I am correct moving  the var stream outside the document code made stream a global var, am I right? Still the button does nothing, it wont switch to an other radio stream :-(

Comment: Yes, "global variable"
 is the correct term for a variable that is in the scope of your entire program.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe not the best solution, but this works for me, my code now starts with;

```
var stream = {

    title: "FSN Radio",
    mp3: "http://212.83.178.251:8050/stream"

}

ready = false;
```

var stream2 = {

```
    title: "FSN Radio",
    mp3: "http://212.83.178.251:8000/stream"

}

ready = false;
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#button_pop").click(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", stream).jPlayer("play");
}); 

$("#button_pop2").click(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", stream2).jPlayer("play");
});
```

Comment: To help with debugging, check out (console.log())[https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object]. It's available in all browsers, not just Chrome. I would recommend debugging with Chrome since it's got the best debugging tools. Throw a console.log inside of your click event handlers and see if the events are actually firing.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that may be the following:

a/ Create a function to init the radio:

```
function start_stream(player) {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({

    ready: function (event) {

        ready = true;

        $(this).jPlayer("play", stream);

    },

    pause: function() {

        $(this).jPlayer("clearMedia");

    },

    error: function(event) {

        if(ready && event.jPlayer.error.type === $.jPlayer.error.URL_NOT_SET) {

            // Setup the media stream again and play it.

            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream).jPlayer("play");
        }
    },
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "mp3",
    preload: "none",
    wmode: "window",
    volume: 0.02,
    solution: 'html,flash',
    keyEnabled: true
    });
}
```

b/ Before that, you have created diferent vars (streams) like this one:

```
var stream = {

    title: "FSN Radio",
    mp3: "http://212.83.178.251:8050/stream"
},

ready = false;
```

c/ Then, anytime you want to change the stream in the radio, you may do the following call:

```
jQuery('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer("destroy");
start_stream(stream); // Being "stream" the variable with the data you want to play
```